# Python Pip first failing ([Errno 2] No such file or directory), then working at second attempt - why?

Tags: python, pip

The first time I use `pip install <new-package>` it fails. Then I execute it again and it is successful. Why?

Details for the first attempt:

```
root@123:/usr/src# ls -lisa /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytz-2018.9.dist-info/METADATA
8791667 24 -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 20704 Jan 22 16:26 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytz-2018.9.dist-info/METADATA
root@123:/usr/src# pip install git+https://<url-to-some-package>
Collecting git+https://<url-to-some-package>
  Cloning https://<url-to-some-package> to /tmp/pip-req-build-vk83727s
Building wheels for collected packages: <some-package>
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for <some-package> ... done
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-p03ffz3v/wheels/54/0f/ee/de883c215f26102bb3885860548be00ef83ce46a18d0007188
Successfully built <some-package>
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytz-2018.9.dist-info/METADATA'
root@123:/usr/src# ls -lisa /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytz-2018.9.dist-info/METADATA
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytz-2018.9.dist-info/METADATA': No such file or directory
root@123:/usr/src# ls -lisa /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytz-2018.9.dist-info
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytz-2018.9.dist-info': No such file or directory
root@123:/usr/src# ls -lisa /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/
total 2048
 9579135   8 drwxrwsr-x  1 root staff   4096 Jan 23 09:29 .
 9579134   8 drwxrwsr-x  1 root staff   4096 May  9  2018 ..
<and-a-lot-more-packages>
```

These shell commands show that by executing `pip install` some files are REMOVED! This is quite confusing.

More info:

- The new package is installed via git+https from a private git repository.
- This output is from a Docker container but the issue happens outside docker as well.
- The git repo of that new package is quite big (couple of hundreds of MB) even though the latest contents are quite small. This might point to a timeout or memory issue. But there are no hints in this respect in the output.
- Environment: pip 19.0, Python 3.6.7, Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The setup.py modules of the private modules were messing with pip (calling `pip install`). So I changed this and everything works now as expected.